# Десериализация полей с private set в контроллере

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, json.net

Библиотека Json.Net поддерживает через рефлексию установку полей с private set, поэтому вполне работают оба варианта:

```
public class Abc1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Abc2
{
    public Abc2(int id, string title)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var request = new Abc1 { Id = 1, Title = "Test" };
    Execute(request);

    var request = new Abc2(1, "Test");
    Execute(request);
}

private void Execute<T>(T request)
{
    var requestSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(requestSerialized);

    request.Dump();
    requestSerialized.Dump();
    deserialized.Dump();
}
```

Однако, несмотря на то, что в [asp.net core от версии 1.0 до версии 2.2 встроен json.net в качестве штатного обработчика json](https://github.com/aspnet/JsonPatch/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch/project.json#L29) - невозможно использовать класссы без конструктора по умолчанию в контроллере:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<object> Update([FromBody] City.Update.Command command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = await this.Mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);
    return result;
}
```

В случае, если у [Command нет конструктора по умолчанию, а есть только private set](https://jimmybogard.com/immutability-in-message-types/) - мы получим null, поля не установятся.

Отчего так и как это можно исправить?

В [asp.net core 3.0 можно будет](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) использовать:

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Но я ещё не тестировал бету.

Команда:

```
using MediatR;

namespace Application.City.Update
{
    public class Command : IRequest<CityData>
    {
        public Command(CityData city)
        {
            this.City = city;
        }

        public CityData City { get; private set; }
    }

    public class CityData
    {
        public CityData()
        {
        }

        public CityData(City city)
        {
            this.Id = city.Id;
            this.Title = city.Title;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public City ToEntity()
        {
            return new City
            {
                Id = this.Id,
                Title = this.Title,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ради интереса попробовал подключить json.net древних версий (в asp.net core встроена 9тая, я пробовал вплоть до 4.0.1) - и всё равно в linqpad работает, а в контроллере нет.

Comment: ну будут у вас модельки изменяемые, какие от этого проблемы? Вы же их нигде, кроме как в методах контроллера, не должны использовать.

Comment: добавь пример Command в сам вопрос

Comment: @Grundy Добавил

Comment: у  City поля get;set;?

Comment: для приведенной команды у меня все нормально десериализацуется. Может проблема не в newtonjson, а в передаваемых данных?

Comment: @Grundy Сохранил Request.Body, попробовал десериализовать вручную. Нет, дело однозначно не в данных. Попробовал копнуть глубже, вроде как получается что проблема в том, что Json.Net только с примитивными типами умеет private set использовать, с классами - нет. :( Оформил ответом, хотя возможно это только стартовая площадка для нового вопроса и надо вопрос грохнуть и по-новой пойти всё переосмыслить.

Comment: @AK,  я делал запрос из браузера со структурой соответствующей твоим классам и они отлично десериализовались

Comment: @Grundy Действительно. В итоге нашёл разницу в коде вопроса и реального кода, спасибо за помощь в поиске ответа.

Comment: @AK, так в чем разница заключалась? :)

Comment: @Grundy Если интересно -- в названии. Кажется, было не `public Command(CityData city)`, а `public Command(CityData cityData)`, типа того, уже не помню точно, но визуально плюс-минус похоже.

Comment: @AK, ага имя параметра на совпадало с тем что в json и все

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если что — это ответ на вопрос, а не дополнение к ответу. :)

В общем, похоже у меня не совсем точное понимание, что именно понимается под тем, как Json.Net обрабатывает private set. Он в принципе это делает, да, но как только речь заходит о составных объектах — начинаются нюансы.

Вот более расширенный пример, чем в вопросе:

```
public class Abc1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DataDto1 Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataDto2
{
    public DataDto2(string noteA, string noteB, string myProperty)
    {
        this.NoteA = noteA;
        this.NoteB = noteB;
        this.Ano = new AnotherDto2(myProperty);
    }

    public string NoteA { get; private set; }
    public string NoteB { get; private set; }
    public AnotherDto2 Ano { get; set; }
}

public class DataDto1
{
    public string NoteA { get; set; }
    public string NoteB { get; set; }
    public AnotherDto1 Ano { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherDto2
{
    public AnotherDto2(string myProperty)
    {
        MyProperty = myProperty;
    }

    public string MyProperty { get; private set; }
}

public class AnotherDto1
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var request = new Abc1 { Id = 1, Title = "Test", Data = new DataDto1 { NoteA = "tA", NoteB = "tB", Ano = new AnotherDto1 { MyProperty = "myPr"} } };
    Execute(request);

    var request = new Abc2(1, "Test", "tA", "tB", "myPr");
    Execute(request);
}
```

Пока всё работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, если на классе DataDto2 поменять определение составного свойства — то оно не установится:

```
public AnotherDto2 Ano { get; private set; }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Аналогично — если объявить private set на самом верхнем уровне для класса, то всё по цепочке будет null.

При этом примитивные типы на верхнем уровне ничуть не реагируют на смену видимости поля.

Итого, с учётом того, что у меня CityData - это плоская Dto всегда состаящая только из примитивных типов (int, string, DateTime) можно выкрутиться следующим образом:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<object> Update([FromBody] City.Update.CityData data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var command = City.Update.Command(data);
    var result = await this.Mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);
    return result;
}
```

Команду тогда можно сделать полностью get only:

```
public class Command : IRequest<CityData>
{
    public Command(CityData city)
    {
        this.City = city;
    }

    public CityData City { get; }
}
```

А для CityData убрать конструктор и проставить все поля в private set:

```
public class CityData
{
    public CityData(City city)
    {
        this.Id = city.Id;
        this.Title = city.Title;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Title { get; private set; }

    public City ToEntity()
    {
        return new City
        {
            Id = this.Id,
            Title = this.Title,
        };
    }
}
```

Update. Альтернативно

[Если проставить атрибут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4066947/5752652) - то сериализация снова подхватывается:

```
[JsonProperty]
public AnotherDto2 Ano { get; private set; }
```

Update2 Спасибо @PavelMayorov за ещё один хороший вариант решения задачи: `[JsonConstructorAttribute]` ([документация](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm))

Update3 Спасибо за помощь @Grundy, который первым обратил внимание на то, что приведённый код должен десериализоваться. Действительно, пример в вопросе не является абсолютно точной копией того кода, который я запускал, при этом взгляд был замылен и я не рассмотрел мелких отличий, которые в итоге повлияли на иной ответ.